# How do I schedule local notifications with complex trigger conditions in Swift (UNNotificationTrigger subclass)?

Tags: swift, triggers, notifications, local

Let me elaborate on the conditions.

I'm building a simple reminder app. The user sets the reminders by toggling on individual days (Su-Sa), setting a start time, and end time, and an interval (every thirty minutes, hour, two hours..)

Currently, I'm setting notifications which repeat weekly from the start time to the end time along the interval for each activated day (when the user selects all 7 days, I do a daily repeat).

Apple's 64 notification limit means cases like "remind me six days a week from 1AM to 11PM" generate too many notifications with a small interval. I'm currently constraining the user, prompting them to make a simpler schedule (which sucks).

Can I use UNNotificationTrigger to schedule a single notification at an array of trigger times, or a conditional trigger that respects a counter? Repeat is great, but I'd like to to disable repeats after the end time, limit the number of repeats somehow, or otherwise get around Apple's limits here.

Comment: No. A notification can only have a single trigger and that can be a specific date/time or a repeat interval but not both